# Strassen matrix multiplication implementation

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have written the below code for Strassen matrix multiplication. I know it's big but you don't need to go through the whole thing. My problem is that during compile time, the Strassen function with parameters of a[][num],b[][num] and c[][num] doesn't have a fixed value of num. This is where i am going wrong. I need to take the input of num in the main and that is why it cannot be globally given a value. How can i fix this? My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num;

void strassen(int a[][num], int b[][num], int c[][num], int size) {

int p1[size/2][size/2], p2[size/2][size/2], p3[size/2][size/2], p4[size/2][size/2], p5[size/2][size/2], p6[size/2][size/2], p7[size/2][size/2];

int temp1[size/2][size/2], temp2[size/2][size/2];

int q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, i, j;

if(size >= 2) { //give recursive calls

//p1

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i][j] + a[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i][j] + b[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p1, size / 2);

//p2

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i + size / 2][j] + a[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i][j];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p2, size / 2);

//p3

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i][j];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i][j + size / 2] - b[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p3, size / 2);

//p4

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i + size / 2][j] - b[i][j];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p4, size / 2);

//p5

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i][j] + a[i][j + size / 2];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p5, size / 2);

//p6

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i + size / 2][j] - a[i][j];

}

}num = size / 2;

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i][j] + b[i][j + size / 2];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p6, size / 2);

//p7

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp1[i][j] = a[i][j + size / 2] - a[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

temp2[i][j] = b[i + size / 2][j] + b[i + size / 2][j + size / 2];

}

}

num = size / 2;

strassen(temp1, temp2, p7, size / 2);

//c11

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

c[i][j] = p1[i][j] + p4[i][j] - p5[i][j] + p7[i][j];

}

}

//c12

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

c[i][j + size / 2] = p3[i][j] + p5[i][j];

}

}

//c21

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

c[i + size / 2][j] = p2[i][j] + p4[i][j];

}

}

//c22

for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < size / 2; j++) {

c[i + size / 2][j + size / 2] = p1[i][j] + p3[i][j] - p2[i][j] + p6[i][j];

}

}

}

else if(size == 1) {

c[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0];

}

}

int padding(int num) {

int original_num = num, lower_power = 0, i, actual_num = 1;

if(num == 1)

return 1;

while(num > 1) {

lower_power++;

num /= 2;

}

for(i = 0; i < lower_power; i++) {

actual_num *= 2;

}

if(actual_num == original_num)

return original_num;

else

return actual_num * 2;

}

int main() {

int i, j, temp;

printf("Enter the size of nxn matrix:\n");

scanf("%d", &num);

temp = num;

if(num <= 0)

return 0;

num = padding(num);

int a[num][num], b[num][num], c[num][num];

printf("Enter matrix a:\n");    //accept inputs for a and b from the user

for(i = 0; i < temp; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < temp; j++) {

scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

}

for(j = temp; j < num; j++) {

a[i][j] = 0;

}

}

for(i = temp; i < num; i++)

for(j = 0; j < num; j++)

a[i][j] = 0;

printf("\nEnter matrix b:\n");

for(i = 0; i < temp; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < temp; j++) {

scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);

}

for(j = temp; j < num; j++) {

b[i][j] = 0;

}

}

for(i = temp; i < num; i++)

for(j = 0; j < num; j++)

b[i][j] = 0;

printf("Matrix a:\n");  //printing the actual matrices for strassen's multiplication

for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < num; j++) {

printf("%d ", a[i][j]);

}

printf("\n");

}

printf("\nMatrix b:\n");

for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < num; j++) {

printf("%d ", b[i][j]);

}

printf("\n");

}

strassen(a, b, c, num);

printf("\nMatrix c is:\n");

for(i = 0; i < temp; i++) {

for(j = 0; j < temp; j++) {

printf("%d ", c[i][j]);

}

printf("\n");

}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (perhaps even should) use `int **` instead, and pass `num` as an argument. As a simplified example, here is how you might compute the sum of a dynamically sized array:

```
int sum(int *in, int len) {
    int out = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        out += in[i];
    return out;
}
```